# header("Content-Type: image/png"); php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

when implement this code i have no image

```
  <?php

  include('confing.php'); 
  echo '<img src="getImage.php?id=2" >';

  ?>
```

file => getImage

```
<html >
<body>
<?php

include('confing.php'); 

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id ";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Set the content type header - in this case image/png
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $row['content'] ;

?>
```

body>
html>
body
html
body>
html>
body
html
body>
html>
body
html
[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The getimage script shouldn't include any HTML. Remove the html tag and the body tag. Images don't have HTML tags in them.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: btw, don't `select *`, select the image column and don't use `...assoc()`, use `...array()`. `fetch_assoc()` fetches a whole bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting:

- `Undefined index ID`: It would appear that you are calling it without passing the ID argument. Obviously you should check that. But also, you should add some error checking to your code to ensure that it doesn't crash if the ID is not passed, or if the ID is invalid.
- `Undefined variable $connection`: Your database connection variable is not set. Maybe you config.inc include doesn't actually set the connection? Or maybe you've got the variable name wrong? You need to check your config.inc to find out why this is happening. In any case, this leads directly onto the next error...
- `mysqli_query expects connection parameter`: Because the `$connection` variable is not set, your DB query can't be run. Some error checking here would be helpful, even if you do sort out the connection variable, as there may be other reasons the connection may fail.
- `mysqli_fetch_assoc expects result parameter`: This occurs because the result variable is not set due to the query not being run. You should add some error checking for this as well, since there may be other reasons why a query fails to run.

The errors didn't even get as far as hitting the `header()` function call, which would also fail because the program has already output some content. You should remove the `<html><body>` tags from the top of the program, as they are not necessary for outputting an image; in fact, they would cause the image to be invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Your line:

```
echo '<img src="getImage.php?id=2">';
```

will output this into your html page:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=2">
```

Second, it will not load, execute and insert the result of getImage.php.

Here's a solution:

First page:

```
<?php
include('getImage.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$img = getImage($id);
echo "<img src='$img' >";
?>
```

getImage.php:

```
<?php
include('confing.php');

function getImage($id){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['content'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: These are not complete PHP pages, you need to adjust them to your needs. Did you call DisplayImage.php?id=2? You need to manage the id param on your own...